# Same path for different domains

Tags: path-aliases, domain-access

I have Drupal 7 with Domain Access on it. 
On the main domain i have an About us page with the path www.example.com/about-us

How can i get same "/about-us" path on several subdomains like domain.example.com/about-us, domain2.example.com/about-us etc. to point to different nodes?

Comment: Something like [Domain Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_path) maybe?

Comment: Well, not actually. It gives multiple paths to the same alias on different domains. I need the same alias for different nodes on different domains.

I've stumbled upon [this module](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_url_alias), and id seems to work the same thing i need, but there aren't any releases for it (?!)

Answer (score 0):

One possible option to create a view page (/about-us) and under filter option make it available on this domain and content type (create a content type for about us and place all about us content under it).